# DB2 SQL Query to Identify what event occured prior to a particular event in a sequence

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table from our IVR that contains a unique call id, sequence number, event code, and event description.  I would like to write a query that let's me know what was the **event prior to a particular event**.

Comment: Do you need to know the last id that has the same event code? Please be more specific

Comment: I just need to know which event code happened prior to event "5047" (Invalid Entry).  so, no I don't need to know the last id that has the same event code.  It should actually be a different event code than the 5047.

Comment: Are you _guaranteed_ that the `sequence` numbers are (properly) sequential, and gaps _never_ appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what indexes exist on the table, a straightforward inner join may receive a better-performing access plan from the query optimizer.

```
SELECT n.call_id, 
    n.event_dt, 
    n.sequence_number, 
    p.call_id as prior_call_id, 
    p.event_id as prior_event_id,
    p.event_dt as prior_event_dt,
    p.sequence_number as prior_sequence_number
FROM daily_events n
INNER JOIN daily_events p
    ON p.sequence_number = n.sequence_number - 1
WHERE n.event_id = '5047'
AND n.event_dt >= DATE( '01/06/2012' ) 
AND n.event_dt <= DATE( '01/07/2012' );
```

The query assumes that any event with a sequence number that differs by one is an appropriate match, and that the call_id doesn't also need to match. If that assumption is incorrect, 
then add `AND n.call_id = p.call_id` to the ON clause of the join.

Comment: I didn't use BETWEEN because it used to (and may still) result in a more expensive plan than the two bounded comparisons.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks Fred!  And thanks for adding the info regarding the call_id.  that was important.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all you have is the particular event's "unique call id":

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE sequence_number = (
    SELECT MAX(sequence_number)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE sequence_number = (
        SELECT sequence_number FROM tbl WHERE unique_id = PARTICULAR_EVENT_UNIQUE_ID
    )
);
```

If the sequence number of the particular event is known (instead or in addition to the unique call id), then the most inner select can be replaced in its entirety by that value.

Comment: Thanks Matt,  I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for.  However, your response made me think of this instead.      SELECT *
         FROM DAILY_EVENTS E
         WHERE E.SEQUENCE_NUMBER = 
                (
                SELECT (E.SEQUENCE_NUMBER - 1) AS PRIORSEQUENCE          
                FROM DAILY_EVENTS E 
                WHERE E.EVENT_ID = '5047'
                AND     E.EVENT_DT BETWEEN '01/06/2012'  AND '01/07/2012'
                )   I'm not sure if it's going to work, since this table sometimes takes hours.  I'll update the question if it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sequence number is sequential (ie. the next record always has a sequence number 1 greater than the current record), try:

```
select i.* 
from ivr_table i
where exists
(select 1
 from ivr_table ni
 where i.sequence + 1 = ni.sequence and ni.event_code = '5047')
```

EDIT: `select null` in subquery replaced with `select 1`

Comment: Mark, it tells me "NULL" is not valid in the context where it is used.

Comment: That's interesting - try using `select 1` instead. (Most databases allow `select null` when checking for existence; I hadn't realised DB2 was different.)

Comment: DB2 tends to want NULL cast as a specific data type, so Mark's adjustment that replaced the NULL dummy/placeholder with 1 is a good move.